# save stack in arraylist

Tags: data-structures, shared-libraries

I want to know how to save stack in array list?

Comment: What language are you using?  Java?

Answer (score 5):

In C# 3.0, you'd do:

```
var list = stack.ToList();  // Returns List<T>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Collections.Generic.Stack<int> myStack = new Stack<int>();
System.Collections.ArrayList myList = new System.Collections.ArrayList(myStack);
```